# wxPython Dirdialog always returns the same directory

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm starting to learn wxPython to create GUI apps, and I am facing some problem: When using wx.DirDialog to pick some folder, no matter what the folder I chose, dlg.GetPath() always return the same folder, which is in my case: /home/loai

my binding function is as follows, it is straight forward :

```
def onButton(self,e):
    dlg = wx.DirDialog(self, "Choose a directory:")
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        print "You chose %s" % dlg.GetPath()
    dlg.Destroy()
```

this always prints :You chose /home/loai

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had the same problem with my own code and with the code posted above. However, I discovered that there is a way around it. When you use DirDialog, do not actually navigate into the directory you want to open. Instead, just highlight the directory you want to open and click open.

On Ubuntu 12.10, with Python 2.7.3, and wxPython 2.8.12.1 (and with 2.9), navigating all the way into a directory and clicking the open button just gives you your home directory. Navigating one directory up, highlighting the desired directory, and clicking the open button gives the correct result.

I have another machine running ubuntu 11.10 with Python 2.7.3 and I don't remember having this problem.

Clearly, this work around is not a proper solution but it's all I've been able to come up with so far. I hope it helps.

Comment: I am running linux mint and since it is build above Ubuntu, it has the same problem :)thanks

Comment: I just confirmed that one one machine, DirDialog give the expected result regardless of whether you go into a directory and click open or just select the directory and click open. That machine is running ubuntu 11.10, python 2.7.2, and wxPython 2.8.11.0.  I don't know if the difference is between wxPython 2.8.11.0 and 2.8.12.1 or if it's something between ubuntu 11.10 and 12.10

Answer (score 6):

What OS are you using? Which Python? Which wxPython? This looks a lot like code from one of my [tutorials](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/26/the-dialogs-of-wxpython-part-1-of-2/), which worked fine for me. I went ahead and actually wrote a stripped-down runnable example from that tutorial:

```
import os
import wx


########################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY,
                          "File and Folder Dialogs Tutorial")
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.currentDirectory = os.getcwd()

        dirDlgBtn = wx.Button(panel, label="Show DirDialog")
        dirDlgBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onDir)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onDir(self, event):
        """
        Show the DirDialog and print the user's choice to stdout
        """
        dlg = wx.DirDialog(self, "Choose a directory:",
                           style=wx.DD_DEFAULT_STYLE
                           #| wx.DD_DIR_MUST_EXIST
                           #| wx.DD_CHANGE_DIR
                           )
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            print "You chose %s" % dlg.GetPath()
        dlg.Destroy()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I ran this code on Windows 7 with Python 2.6.6 and wxPython 2.8.12.1. I selected three different directories and it printed all 3 different paths.

Comment: actually yes, I am learning from your tutorial and this code is form it, my spec are: linux mint 14, python 2.7.3, wxpython 2.8.12.1

Comment: well, it ran in windows 7 and it was OKAY ! I don't know why it won't work with linux mint.

Answer (score 0):

The dir dialogs in most operating systems are clumsy to use.  You have to watch that little text box at the bottom and make sure it's populated correctly before clicking OK.  I have a lot of users that have trouble with this.  So maybe you are navigating to the folder you want, but you are not making the combination of clicks to get your choice into the text box.  This may not be your problem, but I thought I'd mention it.  Otherwise, you code looks fine to me.

good luck,

Mike

Comment: the strange is that here, there is no "little text box", it is just a choose dialog

Comment: I have a windows machine, so mine may look different than yours if you are using a unix-type machine.

Answer (score 0):

## Try this:

dialog = wx.DirDialog(None, "Navigate to Desktop directory of the version you require.",
"~/", 0, (10, 10), wx.Size(400, 300))
dialog.CentreOnParent()

```
    # Update directory with path selected in dialog
    if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        self.dir_path = dialog.GetPath()
        self.updateDirectory()
```

It worked for me :D